# Solving for five unknowns in a 3 x 3 matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I know that

```
matrix.Transpose[matrix] = IdentityMatrix[3]
matrix = {{0.8111, 0.4867, -0.3244}, {a,b,0}, {c,d,e}}
```

I tried

```
LinearSolve[matrix.Transpose[matrix] = IdentityMatrix[3], {a, b, c, d, e}]
```

which gives `{}`. There is an inexact solution:

> `a = -0.5145, b = 0.8575, c = 0.2782, d = 0.1669, e = 0.9459`

How do I derive that result in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Look at the $1,1$ entry of `matrix.Transpose[matrix]`; you should then see why it can't be equated to an identity matrix.

Comment: Study the difference between [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) and [`Equals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equals.html)

Comment: LinearSolve tries to solve the equation m.x = b, where b and x are of same dimensions. In your case the matrix is 3 x 3 and b is 5 x 1. This does not work. What is your original equation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterating @[J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m)'s comment:  This problem has no exact solution.

```
With[{
    matrix = {{0.8111, 0.4867, -0.3244}, {a, b, 0}, {c, d, e}}
  },
  Print[matrix.Transpose[matrix]];
  Solve[
    matrix.Transpose[matrix] == IdentityMatrix[3],
    {a, b, c, d, e}
  ]
]
(*  {{0.999995,... *)
(*  {}  *)
```

That is, the first column's first entry is not $1$, so there is no hope of getting the identity matrix.

You can get "close":

```
With[{
    matrix = {{0.8111, 0.4867, -0.3244}, {a, b, 0}, {c, d, e}}
  },
  NMinimize[
    Norm[matrix.Transpose[matrix] - IdentityMatrix[3]],
    {a, b, c, d, e}
  ]
]

(*  {0.00655597, {a -> 0.514683, b -> -0.854455, c -> 0.275695, d -> 0.170359, e -> 0.947984}}  *)
```

If you demand the signs you have in your inexact solution...

```
With[{
    matrix = {{0.8111, 0.4867, -0.3244}, {a, b, 0}, {c, d, e}}
  },
  NMinimize[{
      Norm[matrix.Transpose[matrix] - IdentityMatrix[3]],
      a < 0, b > 0, c > 0, d > 0, e > 0
    },
    {a, b, c, d, e}
  ]
]

(*  {0.0307611, {a -> -0.535905, b -> 0.854165, c -> 0.287132, d -> 0.198164, e -> 0.943339}}  *)
```

... we can force them, but the residual (the deviation from equality, $0.030...$) is about $5$-times bigger.

Your particular approximate solution has a much smaller residual:

```
With[{
  matrix = {{0.8111, 0.4867, -0.3244}, {a, b, 0}, {c, d, 
    e}} /. {a -> -0.5145, b -> 0.8575, c -> 0.2782, d -> 0.1669, 
    e -> 0.9459}
  },
  Norm[matrix.Transpose[matrix] - IdentityMatrix[3]]
]

(*  0.0000593183  *)
```

which suggests a different method.  Treating the matrix as a $9$-element vector an measuring the discrepancy via Euclidean distance, we get an even better approximation than the one you have:

```
With[{
    matrix = {{0.8111, 0.4867, -0.3244}, {a, b, 0}, {c, d, e}}
  },
  NMinimize[{
      Sqrt[(#.#)] &[Flatten[
        matrix.Transpose[matrix] - IdentityMatrix[3]
      ]],
      a < 0, b > 0, c > 0, d > 0, e > 0},
    {a, b, c, d, e}
  ]
]

{4.54*10^-6, {a -> -0.514527, b -> 0.857474, c -> 0.278165, d -> 0.166913, e -> 0.94592}}
```

Note that this rounds to the approximate solution you have.  Also, the discrepancy is about a factor of $10$ smaller than that for your approximate solution.

Comment: Your last snippet is more compactly done as `With[{matrix = {{0.8111, 0.4867, -0.3244}, {a, b, 0}, {c, d, e}}}, NMinimize[{Norm[matrix.Transpose[matrix] - IdentityMatrix[3], "Frobenius"], a < 0, b > 0, c > 0, d > 0, e > 0}, {a, b, c, d, e}]]`.